# Best way to win a version of dice black jack.

Tags: probability, game-theory

The game has two players, the player (me) and the dealer. The player starts by rolling a 10-sided die. You roll the die as many times as you want adding all your rolls, your goal is to get as close to 21 as possible. If you go over 21 you lose automatically. Once you have rolled the die and decided to stop (and the sum is below 21), the dealer does the same process. If the dealer gets a sum less than or equal to 21 but larger than yours, you get nothing. Otherwise you win. What is the optimal strategy?

My probability is terrible and I have no idea how to tackle this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Two key points: The dealer knows your total and uses it strategically. A tie is considered a win.

Comment: The dealer knows your total and uses it strategically?  That's a big difference between this and ordinary blackjack.  And ties are resolved in your favor?  That's another big difference.  In any case, like most blackjack-like games, simulation is a good idea.  Let the computer play a few thousand games or more.

Comment: @lulu Yes, the dealer knows your total and uses it strategically. A tie is a win.

Comment: So he would roll until he gets more than you essentially. He has no reason to not risk going over 21

Comment: I suggest editing your post to stress those two points, as they are quite distinct from ordinary blackjack rules.  And, again, suggest simulation.  To do it analytically, first consider the dealer's odds (the dealer's strategy is forced:  keep playing until they lose or beat the known score).

Comment: Your strategy only depends on your stopping number. Can you find the best response for the dealer given your strategy?

Comment: @SBF of course, he will roll until he gets larger number than me always even if it means he goes over 21.

Comment: Simulation seems to say that you should stop rolling once you reach $17$, and that you win about $46.15\%$ of the time with that strategy.

Comment: @mjqxxxx We also know that the probability of the dealer winning is at least 50%, also note that if you have below 11 you should definitely keep rolling, and 17 is one above the average of 11 and 21 (what's the probability of 16?)

Comment: Actually I wasn't sure if the dealer would win more or less than half the time... since you winning ties gives you an edge.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Oh I see, I did not count the ties you're correct

Comment: I ran a simulation and it seems you roll until you get 17 or more to get best chances of winning.

Comment: do you only allow for deterministic strategies or mixed ones as well?

Comment: Just intuitively:  I'd have said the dealer has a big advantage in going second.  If you get to, say,  $13$ or $14$, you really need to keep going (it seems to me) and of course you then run a high risk of going bust.  The dealer wins all such situations.

Comment: Shouldn't be all that hard to do it analytically, though it will be messy.  Start with the high cases.  If you get a $21$ you win, no computation needed.  What about $20$?  Calculate the probability that the dealer will hit $21$.  Now, say you hit $19$.  And so on.  Each case is fairly easy but of course there are lots of them.